# Xamarin: Binding Class Object property to ListView Text

Tags: c#, listview, xamarin

I have a List of Objects `List<Shift> ListOfShift = new List<Shift>();` and I want to make the ListView in Xamarin, show the first value of the Shift object in the cell.

Here is my code for my Shift Class:

```
public String StringShift { get; set; }
DateTime StartOfShift { get; set; }
DateTime EndOfShift { get; set; }


    public Shift(DateTime StartShift, DateTime EndShift)
    {
        StartOfShift = StartShift;
        EndOfShift = EndShift;

        StringShift = Convert.ToString(StartOfShift);
    }

    public string StringShow()
    {
        string ShiftText = Convert.ToString(StartOfShift) + " " + Convert.ToString(EndOfShift);
        return ShiftText;
    }
```

And here is the following XAML:

```
<ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ViewCell>
                    <Label Text="{Binding .}" />
                </ViewCell>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
```

I have tried the following:

```
<Label Text="{Binding .}" />
<Label Text="{Binding Shift.StartOfShift}" /> // Prints blank
<Label Text="{Binding Shift.StringShift}" /> // Prints blank
```

How can I make the Text value be the intended object property?

Note:

*The List does work, and items are being added with the proper values, I am able to use the list objects as intended I just want them to be shown.*

EDIT:

Full XAML code

```
<Grid>

<Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
</Grid.ColumnDefinitions>       
<Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
</Grid.RowDefinitions>
<Button
    x:Name="ShiftAdd"
    Clicked="AddButton"
    Text="Add"
    Grid.Column="0"
    Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
    Grid.Row="2"
/>
<ListView 
    x:Name="ShiftListViewer"
    BackgroundColor="AntiqueWhite"
    SeparatorColor="Black"
    Grid.Column="0"
    Grid.ColumnSpan="4"
    Grid.Row="0"
    Grid.RowSpan="2">
<ListView.ItemTemplate>
<DataTemplate>
<ViewCell>
    <Label Text="{Binding Shift.ShiftOfStart}" />
</ViewCell>
</DataTemplate>
</ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
</Grid>
</ContentPage>
```

C# code:

```
//Within a button event

DateTime Shift1 = new DateTime(2018,1,1,10,0,0);
DateTime Shift2 = new DateTime(2018,1,1,19,0,0);
New List<Shift> ListOfShifts = new List<Shift>();
ListOfShifts.Add(new Shift(Shift1, Shift2));

ShiftListViewer.ItemsSource = ListOfShifts;
    ShiftListViewer.BindingContext = "Shift.StartOfShift";
```

Comment: @StacksSlacks How are you binding your ListView? Where is the ItemsSource in your ListView?

Comment: C# code: *ShiftListViewer.ItemSource = ListOfShifts; *

XAML: *<ListView x:Name="ShiftListViewer" // everything else />*

Comment: @StacksSlacks Are you using MVVM? If you take a look here, it's the same problem. Without seeing all of your code in that xaml file, it's hard to say exactly. https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/67596/listview-itemssource-binding-in-xaml-problem

Comment: @SSharp I've added the full XAML

Comment: @SlackStacks Just to rule it out, if you remove ShiftListViewer.BindingContext, and then set the Label Binding to StartOfShift, does it display? I'm not familiar with setting the context that way.

Comment: @SSharp It still displays blank when the ShiftListViewer.BindingContext is removed

Comment: @SlackStacks did you change the label? Also, I would change the list to an ObservableCollection<Shift>, because it won't update with a List when you click the add button.

Comment: @SSharp, the cells in the list increase with per button block so the list is being updated, but each cell label is *blank* but I can still use the values of each list object

Comment: @SlackStacks Did you change the list to ObservableCollection? Look here to see what I mean. You are adding an item to the list, after it's rendered. I don't think it will update that way, it has to be bound to an ObservableCollection to update the UI on that button click event. See here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/listview/data-and-databinding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if your `ItemsSource` is `List<Shift>`, then each element in your `ListView` is of type `Shift`.  That means that the binding expressions will be relative to `Shift`

```
// tries to display Shift object
<Label Text="{Binding .}" />
// won't work, there is no "Shift" property on the Shift object
<Label Text="{Binding Shift.StartOfShift}" /> 
// won't work, there is no "Shift" property on the Shift object
<Label Text="{Binding Shift.StringShift}" /> 

// this should work, "StringShift" is a public property of Shift
<Label Text="{Binding StringShift}" />
```